# Serving images with Yii that are outside of web application folder, performance issue

Tags: php, image, performance, yii

I have the following controller/action:

```
<?php

class ImageController extends CController {

    public function actionView($folder, $name) {

        $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

        $file = Yii::app()->params['images_path'] . $ds . $folder . $ds . $name;

        $content = file_get_contents($file);

        Yii::app()->request->sendFile($file, $content);
    }

}
```

This would be a basic images serving action. My images are outside the web root folder. The problem is how to optimize the reading of the files. Seems like with each request the whole Yii application is executed just to serve one image. And with lots of images on the website it's a big performance issue. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: This is going to be costly; you're reading the full contents of the image file, assigning it to a PHP variable and serving it through the framework. Ideally you want to serve static files like images directly through your HTTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `sendFile()` used to serve downloads and not view file content. 
Honestly i can't understand what you trying to make, but from my practice - files with `sendFile()` can be corrupted. There are different reasons, 1 of them is logging and it also cause some performance issues. 
Remove all loggers except CFileLogRoute.
Can be done in config or in base Controller:

```
public function disableProfilers()
{
    if (Yii::app()->getComponent('log')) {
        foreach (Yii::app()->getComponent('log')->routes as $route) {
            if (in_array(get_class($route), array('CProfileLogRoute', 'CWebLogRoute', 'YiiDebugToolbarRoute','DbProfileLogRoute'))) {
                $route->enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then your download action will be

```
    public function actionDownloadFile()
    {
        $this->disableProfilers();        
        $file = '/path/to/file/some_file.txt';
        Yii::app()->request->sendFile(basename($file),file_get_contents($file));
    }
```

Giving files with php and file_get_contents is efficient operation, so if you have lots of images to serve - give them via HTTP server.